# How to select field values from array of objects?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a JSON column with following JSON

```
{
    "metadata": { "value": "JABC" },
    "force": false,
    "users": [ 
        { "id": "111", "comment": "abc" },
        { "id": "222", "comment": "abc" },
        { "id": "333" }
    ]
}
```

I am expecting list of IDs from the query output `["111","222", "333"]`. I tried following query but getting null value.

```
select colName->'users'->>'id' ids from tableName
```

How to get this specific field value from the array of object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to extract the array as rows and then get the `id`:

```
select json_array_elements(colName->'users')->>'id' ids from tableName;
```

If you're using `jsonb` rather than `json`, the function is `jsonb_array_elements`.